When the JavaScript Reflect.get method has a receiver parameter, it returns undefined. How can this situation be reproduced at the language level?
enter image description here
const globalProxy = new Proxy(win.window, {
  get(target, p, receiver){
    // return undefined
    return Reflect.get(target, p, receiver);
    // there is a value
    // return Reflect.get(target, p);
  }
})

In Node.js version 20.18, when using Reflect.get with the receiver parameter, it returns undefined, while without the receiver parameter, there is a value. Based on my limited understanding of the Reflect.get function (which only affects the this pointer of getters), I really can't figure out why this is the case. I even asked Claude, but it didn't provide me with a reproducible example.
On Node.js version 16.20, there is a value. So, could it be a bug in V8?

code of image comes from vitest lib

when debugging in VSCode, when monitoring the target and expanding the list of member variables, there is no property named p (including expanding the [[Prototype]] prototype layer by layer). However, it exists on __proto__, and hasOwnProperty returns true, which also indicates that it shouldn't be on the prototype.
I can reproduce with this:
const myObj = {
    aa: 'aa'
}

Object.defineProperty(myObj, 'a', {
    get () {
        return this.aa
    }
})

const myProxyObj = new Proxy({
    a: 'a'
}, {
    get(target, prop, receiver) {
        return Reflect.get(target, prop, receiver)
    }
})

console.log(Reflect.get(myObj, 'a', myProxyObj))
console.log('a' in myObj)
console.log('a' in myProxyObj)
console.log(Object.hasOwn(myObj, 'a'))
console.log(Object.hasOwn(myProxyObj, 'a'))

but, in vscode debuger control panel, I get this:
// target === win.window
Object.entries(target).length // 183
Object.keys(target).length // 186

addEventListener aka p is not exists in entries function returns, besides, removeEventListener and dispatchEvent don't exist either
there is a reproduce demo may help: https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/kc2h2l
steps:

add breakpoint in line 4 of dom.test.js file
npm run test in js debug terminal
watch window in debug panel, will get a proxy object
go to definition of proxy [[Handler]]'s get function then add a breakpoint(source map incorrect maybe)
if previous step not work, try to step in (Alt+F11) 2 - 4 times, will reach to line 317 of /node_modules/vitest/dist/vendor-entry.5c1e6d94.js file
now, you can watch target and receiver and reproduce above demo


In
get(target, p, receiver){
    // ...
}

target is the window/globalThis object, p is a string containing the name of the property being accessed, and receiver is the Proxy object.
Edited:
Reflect.get(target, propertyKey, receiver) is semantically equivalent to target[propertyKey]; if the property is a data property (a regular property). However, if the property is an accessor property (a getter/setter) then the getter is bound to the receiver before being called.
I believe this function I have written emulates what Reflect.get does. In all 3 of the test cases it returns the same result.
function whatReflectGetDoes(target, propertyKey, receiver) {
    const getter = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, propertyKey).get;
    if (getter === undefined) {
        return target[propertyKey];
    } else {
        return getter.bind(receiver)();
    }
}

var obj = {
    foo: 42,    // data property
    get bar() { // accessor property
      return 21;
    },
};

// REAL 42 21
console.log("REAL", obj.foo, obj.bar);
// FAKE 42 21
console.log("FAKE", whatReflectGetDoes(obj, 'foo'), whatReflectGetDoes(obj, 'bar'));

// -----------------------

var obj = {
    bar: 42,
    get foo() {
       return this.bar;
    }
};

// REAL 21 42
console.log("REAL", Reflect.get(obj, 'foo', {bar: 21}), Reflect.get(obj, 'bar', {bar: 21}));
// FAKE 21 42
console.log("FAKE", whatReflectGetDoes(obj, 'foo', {bar: 21}), whatReflectGetDoes(obj, 'bar', {bar: 21}));

// -----------------------

var obj = {
    aa: "aa",
};

Object.defineProperty(obj, "a", {
    get() {
        return this.aa;
    },
});

const myProxyObj = new Proxy(
    { a: "a" },
    {
        get(target, prop, receiver) {
            return Reflect.get(target, prop, receiver);
        },
    }
);
// REAL undefined
console.log("REAL", Reflect.get(myObj, "a", myProxyObj));
// FAKE undefined
console.log("FAKE", whatReflectGetDoes(myObj, "a", myProxyObj));

There is not a bug in V8 because if you look at the ECMAScript specification here https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/reflection.html#sec-reflect.get it indicates that what my whatReflectGetDoes function does is the intended behavior. Rather I believe Mozilla's Reflect.get documentation (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/get) is incomplete.

there is a reproduce demo, thx for your help: https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/kc2h2l

ok I see. I looked into it more and updated my answer because it would have been too long to post in a comment.
